# Input text box not editable with jQuery Draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I call a javascript function that dynamically builds `<li>`'s with a text input box and drop down inside.  The drop down works fine with jQuery's Draggable but I cannot edit the input text box?

```
function addField(type){
  var html = '';
  html += '<li class="ui-state-default">';
  if(type == 'text'){
   html += '<b>Text Field</b><br />';
   html += 'Field Name: <input type="text" name="text" id="text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
   html += 'Field Size: <select name="textSize" id="textSize' + fRank + '"><option value="small">Small</option><option selected value="medium">Medium</option><option value="large">Large</option><option value="large2">Large 2 Lines</option><option value="large3">Large 3 Lines</option><option value="large4">Large 4 Lines</option></select>';
  }
  html += '</li>';
  $("#sortableFields").append(html);

  $(function() {
       $( "#sortableFields" ).sortable({
      revert: true
    });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
           connectToSortable: "#sortableFields",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    cancel: ':input,option'
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();  
             });
}
```

I have played around with the cancel option but it doesn't help.

What do you suggest?

Comment: What browser are you using? It works fine for me in Chrome + Firefox. It might be a z-index issue somewhere in your css, where you have an invisible div extending over the input box and preventing you to click on it. Edit: Ah, I see you can, however, not select text within the input box, or get the carot to go anywhere but the last letter - I assume that's what you mean by your question.

Comment: Removing the disableSelection() line fixes the problem, and everything still works fine (in FF & Chrome). Otherwise you might opt for Pointy's answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the problem is with your use of `.disableSelection()` for the `<li>` elements. Instead of doing that, put the text (stuff outside your `<input>`) into `<span>` elements, and then disable the spans

```
$('li > span').disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('li.ui-state-default').on( 'click', 'input', function () {    
    $(this).focus();
});
```

It works for me.

Comment: Even for me disableSelection() didn't work but focusing the input worked like a charm!

Comment: A more practical solution maybe is to use the **cancel** setting of sortable widget as the asking user already did, maybe he has done it in the wrong way (I've not studied his problem and code)... (?)

Comment: @Redips77 I was using cancel in my options too, and never worked. Forcing the focus on the input when click has been the solution for me. +1

Comment: However, it would be preferable to write `$(document).on( 'click', 'li.ui-state-default input', function() { ... } );` to support dynamically added inputs

Answer (score 0):

It was good for me:

```
    $('input').bind('click.sortable mousedown.sortable',function(ev){
        ev.target.focus();
    });
```

[original answer](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4429)